# Lubuntu 15.04, android-studio, подключение телефона

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

Lubuntu 15.04, android-studio.

Запускаю студию

```
:~$ sudo sh ./studio.sh
```

lsusb девайс видит, но не отображает имя.

```
:~$ lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 2970:0c02  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Смотрим на сам дивайс, все в порядке.

```
:~$ lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/001/011
Device: ID 2970:0c02  
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x2970 
  idProduct          0x0c02 
  bcdDevice            2.16
  iManufacturer           2 Fly
  iProduct                3 IQ4514 Quad
  iSerial                 4 0123456789ABCDEF
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           62
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              5 MTP
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x001c  1x 28 bytes
        bInterval               6
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass     66 
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

adb devices показывает 1 пустую строку (как я понимаю эта пустая строка и есть мой дивайс)

```
:~$ adb devices 
List of devices attached 

:~$
```

Пробовал давать права 777 /dev/bus/usb/001/011.
Пробовал делать все под root.
android-studio вообще не видит девайс.
Отключал, подключал USB.
udev reload
В телефоне поставил отладку по USB, включил режим "для программистов".
Честно испробовал все, что только попалась по запросам:

```
ubuntu lsusb device without name
ubuntu lsusb device
ubuntu adb empty list
ubuntu adb doesn't see device
ubuntu android studio doesn't see device
etc.
```

Может все проще? Как сделать так чтобы android-studio увидело девайс? Перепробовал 100500 смежных решений по данному вопросу, не сработали.

Comment: вы уверены, что прошивка телефона поддерживает работу с `adb`? вот [здесь](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#VendorIds) этот идентификатор (2970) отсутствует.

Comment: да фиг его знает, опровержения в инете нету...

Answer (score 2):

Закройте студию и работайте только с adb. На данном этапе студия будет только мешать. Да и её не стоит запускать через sudo.

Устройство должно быть подключено, в настройках включена отладка по USB.

Добавьте в файл `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` строку (Каталог `.android` и этот файл уже должны созданы у вас в home):

```
0x2970
```

Посмотрите `adb devices`.

Если не помогло, то дальше будет стандартный мануал.

Создайте файл `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` с содержимым:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2970", MODE="0666"
```

Установите чтение для всех на этот файл:

```
$ sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Убейте все запущенные процессы adb, если они есть

```
$ sudo killall adb
```

Перезапустите udev:

```
$ sudo service udev restart
```

Посмотрите ещё раз `adb devices`.

Если и это не помогло, то попробуйте тупо сменить USB кабель. С такими телефонами обычно идут кабели очень низкого качества. Ну или либо он у вас просто слишком длинный. В таких случаях часто ничего не работает, хотя и устойство отображается в `lsusb`.