# ADT Eclipse не видит реальное устройство при запуске приложения

Tags: android, ubuntu, eclipse, android-adb

Перешел с Win7 на Ubuntu. Использую Eclipse. Подключил свой девайс для запуска на нем приложений через usb. В настройках включил опцию отладки через usb. При запуске проекта Eclipse выдает сообщение:

> No compatible targets were found. Do you wish to add a new Android Virtual Device?

Как я понимаю, нужно где-то указать для Ubuntu, что можно выполнять отладку на реальных устройствах?

Или еще все банальнее: нету установленных драйверов?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/55661/ , http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424142/ - есть такие ответы